# Error of a Taylor Polynomial

Tags: taylor-expansion

$Arctan(0,2)$ can be represented by
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ at x=0,2.Calculate $arctan(0,2)$ with an error less than $5.10^{-5}$.

In this question,I have done the necessary operations and obtained the error(remainder) as $$\frac{(0,2)^{2n+3}}{2n+3}$$.But to show that this is less than $5.10^{-5}$ , I must take n as 2.So,why is n taken as 2?

Comment: Check your formulas. You cannot have the exact value of the error, since then you could sum the error to the polinomial and obtain the exact value of the arctan.

Comment: No,my formula is correct.My question is different.If n is taken as 2,then the inequality holds.My teacher has already given me a hint that suggests n to be taken as 2.But i could not understand why should n be taken as 2.

Comment: Well i'm not going to check if the work is correct but $2$ is the least positive integer so the error term is within that tolerance.

Comment: What does " $\arctan (0,2)\;$" mean?

Comment: Oh, I think that means $\;\arctan0.2=\arctan\frac15\;$ ...

Comment: Yes,you are correct

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ is alternating which means that the error is lest than the first neglected terms.

So, summing up to $m$, the remainder is, in absolute value, $$R_m=\frac{x^{2m+1}}{2m+1}$$ and you want it to be less than $\epsilon$. There is a rigorous solution for $m$ of equation $$\frac{x^{2m+1}}{2m+1}=\epsilon$$ It is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$m=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{\epsilon }\right)}{2 \log (x)}-\frac{1}{2}$$ In your case, the argument of $W(z)$ is $z=20000 \log (5)$ which is quite large; so we can approximate the result using the exapnsion given in the Wikipedia page $$W(z)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\cdots\qquad \qquad (L_1=\log(z)\qquad L_2=\log(L_1))$$ which makes $W(20000 \log (5))\approx 8.265$ and then $m=2.067$.

So, you need three terms to be added.

Let us check
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
m & R_m & \approx \\
 1 & \frac{1}{375}      & 0.00266667 \\
 2 & \frac{1}{15625}    & 0.00006400 \\
 3 & \frac{1}{546875}   & 0.00000183 \\
 4 & \frac{1}{17578125} & 0.00000006
\end{array}
\right)$$